# MongoDB unregistered authentication error Centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos7

After reconfigure mongod.conf when trying to start mongod.service I'm getting error message.

I tried to run the command "mongod -f /path-to-configuration-file/

but everything is going ok so I tried to give permitions to db and log folder running the commands:

1 - chmod 777 /path-to-files

2 - chown mongod:mongod /path-to-files -R

After doing that I tried to give permition to port 40017  but still getting error.

> My mongod.conf file:
>
> ```html
> # mongod.conf
>
> # for documentation of all options, see:
> #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
>
> # where to write logging data.
> systemLog:
>   destination: file
>   logAppend: true
>   path: /bin/rsmongo/log/mongod.log
>
> # Where and how to store data.
> storage:
>   dbPath: /bin/rsmongo/data/db
>   journal:
>     enabled: true
> #  engine:
> #  mmapv1:
> #  wiredTiger:
>
> # how the process runs
> processManagement:
>   fork: true  # fork and run in background
>   pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
>   timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
>
> # network interfaces
> net:
>   port: 40017
> ```
>
> Systemctl status mongod.service result:

```html
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Ter 2018-12-18 14:02:01 BRST; 9s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3880 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3877 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3874 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3872 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: 2018-12-18T14:02:01.128-0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: forked process: 3883
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

> Journalctl -xe reult:

```html
Dez 18 14:01:01 bon-lap-srv01 CROND[3850]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Dez 18 14:01:01 bon-lap-srv01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3853]: starting 0anacron
Dez 18 14:01:01 bon-lap-srv01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3859]: finished 0anacron
Dez 18 14:01:01 bon-lap-srv01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3861]: starting 0yum-hourly.cron
Dez 18 14:01:01 bon-lap-srv01 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3865]: finished 0yum-hourly.cron
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 polkitd[1006]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3867:1091339 (system bus name :1.51 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/fr
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
-- Subject: Unidade mongod.service sendo iniciado
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade mongod.service está sendo iniciada.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: 2018-12-18T14:02:01.128-0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: forked process: 3883
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 mongod[3880]: To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
-- Subject: A unidade mongod.service falhou
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- A unidade mongod.service falhou.
--
-- O resultado é failed.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Dez 18 14:02:01 bon-lap-srv01 polkitd[1006]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:3867:1091339 (system bus name :1.51, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, loc
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I deleted a file called "mongodb-40017.sock" at /tmp  folder then it worked as expected.